# use web3js and infura deploy contract

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, infura

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
let web3;
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/my key'));
}
const source = fs.readFileSync('./contract/coin.sol', 'utf8');
const compile = solc.compile(source, 1);
const contractCompile = Object.values(compile.contracts)[0];
const deployAddr = '0x.....';
const contractByteCode = '0x' + contractCompile.bytecode;
const contractAbi = JSON.parse(contractCompile.interface);
const gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: contractByteCode});
const gasPrice = '20000000000';
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, {
    from: deployAddr,
    gas: '15000000',
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
});
const initialSupply = 10000000000;
const tokenName = 'LLT';
const tokenSymbol = 'LLT';

myContract.deploy({
    data: contractByteCode,
    arguments: [initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol]
}).send({
    from: deployAddr,
    gas: '15000000',
    gasPrice: gasPrice
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) {console.log(transactionHash)})
.on('receipt', function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
}).on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
}).then(function (newContractInstance) {
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error: failed to deploy, detail:", err)
});
```

I get `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""` when I use node to run this code.

How can I solve this problem？ Thank you

Comment: The thing I noticed was: ```new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/my key'))``` should be:  ```new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'))```  I don't know if this will solve the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.sendRawTransaction()` instead of `.send()`, so:

```
myContract.deploy({
    data: contractByteCode,
    arguments: [initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol]
}).sendRawTransaction({
    from: deployAddr,
    gas: '15000000',
    gasPrice: gasPrice
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.on('transactionHash', function (transactionHash) {console.log(transactionHash)})
.on('receipt', function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
}).on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
}).then(function (newContractInstance) {
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error: failed to deploy, detail:", err)
});
```

I am not sure it can works, probably you have to prepare and sign the transaction before send it using Infura.

Comment: Error: TypeError: myContract.deploy(...).sendRawTransaction is not a function

Comment: Please check official API documentation of your web3js version. There are may be a lot of breaking changes, since it still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using Metamask and actually use their provider, therefore going into the true of this condition:

> if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
>   web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
>   }
>   else {
>        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/my key'));
>   }

so this could happen because of a sync issue with metamask(I got it a few times when using a custom RPC node)
my suggestion is to try going to MM settings and reset account(it will only delete transactions) and if that doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling metamask

Answer (score 0):

Besides the comment, correctly stating the missing infura key, this cannot work, as you do not have a code component actually signing the transaction. The referenced web3 api here relies on node clients with private keys to do that, which is of course not feasible with infura. Try [this](https://gist.github.com/tomconte/8ef602bf38c4dd11a6b47b7e1114e30c) solution instead, consider the last comment of that gist also.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you are trying to deploy a contract from an address (deployAddr) but you are *not sending any private key* to verify the ownership of that address (deployAddr).

So you need to **add a private key of that address (deployAddr) before deploying** the contract, like this:

```
const add = await web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(privateKeyOfDeployAddr);
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers!