# How can I upload a smart contract to the Ethereum blockchain directly from a Raspbian Terminal without Parity, Geth, etc installed?

Tags: solidity, dapps

How can I upload a smart contract to the Ethereum blockchain directly from a Raspbian Terminal without Parity, Geth, etc installed?

Hello,

I primarily use a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian OS installed as my main computer.

I would like to upload my smart contracts directly from the terminal to the Ethereum blockchain without using a browser OR parity OR geth etc.

Is it possible and if so how?

Vesa

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible by using a web3 provider that runs on the mainnet. I think that infura (i.e. the same company of metamask) can be used to perform what you ask.
Essentially you need this piece of code (taken from [this github link](https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/c8b30db96d7532e15f85fcfe72ac719c)):

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

// connect to Infura node
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/INFURA_KEY'))
```

Then you can actually send transactions (and therefore deploy contracts) as if you were running a geth instance locally, by following the common procedures. You need an infura key that can be obtained [on this link](https://infura.io/signup).

You will need node and the web3 node package (`npm install web3`), but this approach does not require neither a graphical user interface nor a synced geth instance on your raspberry.

Comment: But how do I pay Infura for uploading the contract? The deployment fee I mean.

Comment: Deploying a contract to the blockchain is not free, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to pay fees for the deploying to the miner. This means that you need to have an Ethereum address with a sufficient amount of Ether to pay the deployment. If you take a look to the GitHub link, you can see that the author specify the address and the private key to sign a transaction. You need to make something analogous. Maybe this link can help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50362/use-web3js-and-infura-deploy-contract

Comment: Really? It's safe to transfer the private key like that?

Comment: If you check the link, I do not think it sends the private key, but rather it uses the module ethereumjs-tx to sign a transaction. So the private key is used only locally. You send to infura only the signed transaction...

Comment: Ok, I will try with a test account. Thanks for the advice. I knew about Infura already but these instructions are specific enough to give it a try.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: I have not had time to test it yet