# Ethereum Decentralized Wallet Service API

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, decentralization, decentralized-exchange

With the decentralized nature of the blockchain space it makes sense for this to be a thing.

I **need** a wallet API service that does not store private keys, allows our servers to create a wallet & send and receive Ether & ERC20 tokens through an API calls.

I **prefer** something with all of the needs and it's decentralized.

I've considered just building a wallet service to meet my **need.** Would this be ape s@!# hard or pretty straight forward? My background is research side ML/AI and distributed systems. Any help would be appreciated thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you check infura? Maybe the answer to this question (including the comments) can help you.. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52788/how-can-i-upload-a-smart-contract-to-the-ethereum-blockchain-directly-from-a-ras/52799#52799

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Web3.js is sufficient for this. Create keys using Web3.js, sign transactions/messages with Web3.js, then connect to a node provider (likely Infura, but could be a local node as well) to send the transactions